# How to deal with large sizes of data such as array or just number that causing stack in Cpp?

Tags: c++

its my first time dealing with large numbers or arrays and i cant avoid over stacking i tried to use long long to try to avoid it but it shows me that the error is int main line :

**CODE:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   long long n=0, city[100000], min[100000] = {10^9}, max[100000] = { 0 };
   cin >> n;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       cin >> city[i];
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
   {//min
       for (int s = 0; s < n; s++) 
       {
           if (city[i] != city[s]) 
           {
               if (min[i] >= abs(city[i] - city[s])) 
               {
                   min[i] = abs(city[i] - city[s]);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
   {//max
       for (int s = 0; s < n; s++) 
       {
           if (city[i] != city[s]) 
           {
               if (max[i] <= abs(city[i] - city[s])) 
               {
                   max[i] = abs(city[i] - city[s]);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       cout << min[i] << " " << max[i] << endl;
   }
}
```

```
**ERROR:**
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C6262   Function uses '2400032' bytes of stack:  exceeds /analyze:stacksize '16384'.  Consider moving some data to heap.
```

then it opens chkstk.asm and shows error in :
test    dword ptr [eax],eax     ; probe page.

Comment: use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)'s instead.

Comment: Do not use a C array but a C++ vector. It uses heap allocated memory which has no space limitation.

Comment: Your compiler has these error codes which ID the problem regardless of the language of the error message. You should use that to search for similar issues first: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=C6262. In short, your question has been answered many times in the past. As a new user here, please also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Small optimistic remark:

100,000 is not a large number for your computer! (you're also not dealing with that many arrays, but arrays of that size)

Error message describes what goes wrong pretty well:

You're creating arrays on your current function's "scratchpad" (the stack). That has very limited size!

This is C++, so you *really* should do things the (modern-ish) C++ way and avoid manually handling large data objects when you can.

So, replace

```cpp
long long n=0, city[100000], min[100000] = {10^9}, max[100000] = { 0 };
```

with (I don't see any case where you'd want to use `long long`; presumably, you want a 64bit variable?)
(`10^9` is "10 XOR 9", not "10 to the power of 9")

```
constexpr size_t size = 100000;
constexpr int64_t default_min = 1'000'000'000;
uint64_t n = 0;
std::vector<int64_t> city(size);
std::vector<int64_t> min_value(size, default_min);
std::vector<int64_t> max_value(size, 0);
```

---

Additional remarks:

- Notice how I took your 100000 and your 10⁹ and made them `constexpr` constants? Do that! Whenever some non-zero "magic constant" appears in your code, it's a good time to ask yourself "will I ever need that value somewhere else, too?" and "Would it make sense to give this number a name explaining what it is?". And if you answer one of them with "yes": make a new `constexpr` constant, even just directly above where you use it! The compiler will just deal with that as if you had the literal number where you use it, it's not any extra memory, or CPU cycles, that this will cost.
- Matter of fact, that's even bad! You pre-allocating not-really-large-but-still-unneccesarily-large arrays is just a bad idea. Instead, read `n` first, *then* use that `n` to make `std::vectors` of that size.
- Don **not** `using namespace std;`, for multiple reasons, chief among them that now your `min` and `max` variables would shadow `std::min` and `std::max`, and if you call something, you never know whether you're actually calling what you mean to, or just the function of the same name from the `std::` namespace. 
   Instead `using std::cout; using std::cin;` would do for you here!
- This might be beyond your current learning level (that's fine!), but

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  cin >> city[i];
}
```

is inelegant, and with the `std::vector` approach, if you make your `std::vector` really have length `n`, can be written nicely as:

```cpp
for (auto &value: city) {
    cin >> value;
}
```

This will also make sure you're not accidentally reading more values than you mean when changing the length of that `city` storage one day.

- It looks as if you're trying to find the minimum and maximum absolute distance between `city` values. But you do it in an incredibly inefficient way, needing multiple loops over 10⁵·10⁵=10¹⁰ iterations.

  - Start with the maximum distance: assume your `city` vector, array (whatever!) were sorted. What are the two elements with the greatest absolute distance?
  - If you had a sorted array/vector: how would you find the two elements with the smallest distance?

Comment: Given that `city` has been explicitly initialised in your code (and the OP's) with 100000 elements, the `for (auto &value: city) {cin >> value;}` does not do the same thing as `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {cin >> city[i];}`.   Instead of creating vectors with 100000 elements, it would be better to initialise them AFTER reading `n`, with a size of `n` instead of 100000.    Also, rather than being a `long long`, it would be better if `n` was of type `std::size_t` i.e. the same size that `vector` uses to track and report its size.

Comment: @Peter you're right, that bullet point already assumes the bullet point two above was implemented. Let me clarify.

Comment: @Peter i would say that's my first time dealing with std::Vector so is there any way to start knowing more about it because i created the vectors ,but i am not sure how to fill them with data as i used to with for loop (in the basic way"at least for me")or get the data back and use them for calculations ,like i'm trying to reach the max and min value between the values in the array/vector(City)

Comment: @ZeBOy https://cppreference.com should be a bookmark for your browser :)

Comment: @ZeBOy and you **really** want to read my last bullet point. The way you're searching for this is... bad. Not from a programming point of view, but from an *algorithm* point of view.